# How to forward a directory using htaccess with a question mark in it?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do you forward a directory with a question mark in it?

I'm trying to use htaccess to forward all requests, however the URL I need to forward has a question mark in it and for the life of me, I have tried everything but cannot get anything to work because of that question mark.

I'm trying to forward this:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?/
```

To this:

```
http://domain.com/
```

What can I put in my htaccess to do this?

The goal is so that old references to this URL will automatically forward to the new URL structure. Example:

Old URL Structure

```
http://domain.com/index.php?/topic/
```

New URL Structure:

```
http://domain.com/topic/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?(/\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How can I change this so that it also forwards the rest of the URL past that directory? This is sending everything to the root and doesn't pass along the rest of the URL.

Comment: No, sir, that doesn't work either. I updated my original post with an example that includes the old URL structure and what I'm trying to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whooohooo! That worked great! Thank you a thousand times, I really appreciate the assistance!

Comment: @anubhava - just curious... Why the question mark in the: `/%1?` replacement part?

Comment: That question mark is used to strip off existing query string.